# Отображение только вертикальной прокрутки в jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, javascript, прокрутка, плагин

Люди добрые, может кто и знает, что именно в `jScrollPane` отвечает за использование только одной из прокруток: горизонтальной или вертикальной? По идее это должна быть строка в правилах, прописываемых при инициализации плагина. Я пробовал играться с шириной контента и его родительских блоков, чтобы убрать горизонтальную прокрутку, надеясь, что плагин работает от ширины контента, но ничего не вышло. Бьюсь уже третьи сутки. Облегчите мои муки, плиз.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, но ответ был найден на Stackoverflow: [How do I disable horizontal scrollbar in jScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404944/how-do-i-disable-horizontal-scrollbar-in-jscrollpane-jquery) . Нужно было указать при инициализации плагина ширину контента таким образом:

```
$('#element').jScrollPane({
   contentWidth: '0px'
});
```

Вот и все.